# command returning different outputs from powershell remoting from domain server and workstation

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I am getting different outputs for "repadmin /replsum" command in powershell remoting :

when running from a domain server using powershell remoting I'm getting :

```
Replication Summary Start Time: 2017-02-19 04:55:04
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  .....
Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC1                   12h:12m:59s    1 /   5   20  (1908) Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
 DC2                       01m:12s    0 /   5    0  

Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC1                       01m:12s    0 /   5    0  
 DC2                   12h:12m:59s    1 /   5   20  (1908) Could not find the domain controller for this domain.
```

for the same user I'm running repadmin /replsum from a workstation using powershell remoting,I'm getting :

```
Replication Summary Start Time: 2017-02-19 04:55:47
Beginning data collection for replication summary, this may take awhile:
  .....
Source DSA          largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC2                       01m:55s    0 /   5    0  
Destination DSA     largest delta    fails/total %%   error
 DC1                       01m:55s    0 /   5    0  
Experienced the following operational errors trying to retrieve replication information:
         110 - DC2.kono.com
```

why are the results different when i'm using the **same user and target server(which is a domain controller)** for psremoting ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nested powershell session seems to solve the problem :

```
$Password = convertto-securestring "mypassword" -asplaintext -force;
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "kono\administrator",$Password;
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ip -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
$Password = convertto-securestring "mypassword" -asplaintext -force;
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "kono\administrator",$Password;
Invoke-Command -ComputerName dc2 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {repadmin /replsum}
}
```